# Check if window pathname(url) has specific value

Tags: jquery

Good Day.

I want to check if the current browser window pathname has a specific value or not...

But my code is not working...Any help?

```
               jQuery(function($){
                    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

                    if ($pathname == 'http://google.com') {
                        alert($pathname);
                    }
                });
```

thank you

Comment: Looking at the console would have made the error clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($pathname == 'http://google.com') {
```

should be

```
if (pathname == 'http://google.com') { //no $
```

because you declared it as

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: I actually had it like that, but it did not work either...see my fiddle...just update the url...  http://jsfiddle.net/VHUA3/13/

Comment: @DavidVanStaden In the fiddle you are not executing the function. Also since you are in JSFiddle the `pathname` will NOT be the URL. You should use `window.location.href`.

Comment: Ok then I am missing something here. I want to listen to the url in the browser, and if it matches my criteria, it should execute code...How would I do that then?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden `if (window.location.href == 'something') { ... }`

Comment: OK cool man. thank you for your help. I played around with it and I see that the pathname is not the url but the part following the url...ie. everything after http://url.com